# AlamofireObjectmapper encoding the model properities

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

I am using `ObjectMapper` and `Realm`

```
class User:Object, Mappable {
     dynamic var name: String?
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
     name <- map["Name"]
}
```

`ObjectMapper` is converting character **'** is converting to some junk charater by default.

Please recommend me best approach to do removingPercentEncoding from my side

Now my question is i want to apply removingPercentEncoding to name before saving it model and Realm.

How can I do this?

Comment: What's the actual value of `Name` on the json? does it contains an extra `'`?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by removingPercentEncoding manually.

```
 func mapping(map: Map) {
    if let tempName = map.JSON["Name"]{
                name = (tempName as! String).removingPercentEncoding
            }
}
```

I am doing this in my model.But I want to do at a common place.are there suggestions.